laravel docker database refused to connect
I am dockerizing my laravel application but I am getting this error
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = artisanoga and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2 as php

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y unzip libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath

#RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
#    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

COPY --from=composer:2.7.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV PORT=8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "/docker/entrypoint.sh" ]

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:

    # PHP Service
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
                - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        environment:
            - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
            - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - database

volumes:
    db-data: ~

.env
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"


Where is the database actually running?  Your config shows DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 but that IP address refers to the current container in Docker, not to a different container or to a non-container database on the host system.

There are a few options to connect to a database. One is to run the database on your local machine and connect to it using the special host.docker.internal hostname.
Your .env should contain:
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal

Another option is to specify a database service in your docker-compose.yml:
database:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1

Then add this to your .env:
DB_HOST=database

Since you're using Laravel, you can also have a look at Laravel Sail, which sets up and manages the Docker environment for you: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sail
